# "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte" when converting CSV to XLSX format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to download a csv file online and convert it into an excel for further use and I am getting this error. I tried using utf-16 encoding and it did work but not completley as it was merging the columns of the csv when converted to xlsx. I want them separated. How to use utf-8 only to do this?

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Abhishek Sebin\\Downloads\\Keyword Stats " + d1 + " at " + t1 + ".csv",encoding="utf-8")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\Abhishek Sebin\\Downloads\\Keyword Stats " + d1 + " at " + t1 + ".xlsx",encoding='utf-8')

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of you excel?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `engine='openpyxl'`

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Abhishek Sebin\\Downloads\\Keyword Stats " + d1 + " at " + t1 
+ ".csv",encoding="utf-8")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\Abhishek Sebin\\Downloads\\Keyword Stats " + d1 + " at
" + t1 + ".xlsx",encoding='utf-8',engine='openpyxl')

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

writer.save()
```